# Which design patterns we need to use in Microservice Architecture when we use API Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices

I have checked various documents and could see there are couple of design patterns in Microservices.

```
Aggregator Design Pattern
API Gateway Design Pattern
Chained or Chain of Responsibility Design Pattern
Asynchronous Messaging Design Pattern
Database or Shared Data Design Pattern
Event Sourcing Design Pattern
Circuit Breaker Design Pattern
Decomposition Design Pattern
etc.
```

I am going to use `API Gateway` in Microservices. As I am using `API Gateway`, I am using `API Gateway Design Pattern` obviously. I am also having `Database per Service`, so I am using `Database per Service Design Pattern` as well. I am also using `Asynchronous Messaging` for inter service communications. So in that case I am using `Asynchronous Messaging Design Pattern` as well.

So basically, I am combining multiple Design Patterns like `API Gateway Design Pattern`, `Database per Service Design Pattern` & `Asynchronous Messaging Design Pattern`. So is it correct to combine multiple design patterns together when designing Microservices or we should stick to only one Design Pattern?

**Note**: I will be writing Microservices in Java & Spring Boot.

Comment: This question is not suitable for stackoverflow. There are no hard rules which say your design is correct or not. It all depends on your use case. Instead of picking design patterns first, initial step would be a high level design for your use case. Though, in the end you will find you are using multiple design patterns.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. Where should I post it then?

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to use the same design pattern all over your software.**

So actually, every functionality may, according to its own needs, comprise of a recognised design pattern which is most likely to be efficient while solving that kind of problem; if at all there are multiple solutions to it!

So, its very likely that the pattern we may use in our various functionalities of our project may **depend on what that feature is doing.** The reason being that, every architecture by definition, is targeted towards solving a different set of **business requirements!** And therefore, every architecture will eventually use **its own set of patterns.. .**

You can safely assume that any reasonable system will use multiple patterns. However, without understanding thoroughly what your requirements will be for that specific, you cant jump on to like, "I will use this specific pattern only".

I strongly recommend the book "Head first design patterns" which is a superb introduction to design patterns, which will help you to understand the "why" part of design patterns, and not just the "what".

One precaution you may take is to avoid random articles from places like CodeProject and stick to the book "Head first design patterns", because to truly understand the concept, the book will be good for developing your skill in the field.